# ConTeXt: Remove vertical space before heading

Tags: sectioning, titles, context

I cannot eliminate the space before a heading. I’ve tried adding all variants of `before=\nowhitespace`, but I was unsuccessful. Minimal example:

```
\showframe
\setuppapersize[S33]
\setuphead [title] [style=\bfd]

\starttext
  % This text touches the top border
  {\bfd Foobar}

  % This text has a small space above
  \starttitle[title=Foobar]
  \stoptitle
\stoptext
```

Notice the small gap above the text on the second page. With bigger text sizes and different fonts, this can be very noticeable.

[image: rendered PDF]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ConTeXt inserts a strut by default. You have to disable it using `strut=no`

```
\showframe
\setuppapersize[S33]
\setuphead [title] [strut=no,style=\bfd]

\starttext
  \starttitle[title=Foobar]
  \stoptitle
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Although actually, that behaviour is quite useful – could I set the normal text to use a strut also?

Comment: @JurajFiala Doesn't grid typesetting do that job? If you want to arbitrarily insert a strut somewhere, there's TeX's `\strut`. Let me know if I understood well.

Comment: Yes, I guess grid typesetting is the way to go.

Comment: Just a note for anyone wondering – the get `\strut` to scale, I had to use `\setupstrut` after the font change.